# How to make a hole in a DIV (transpare elements below)

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove part of a DIVs color without changing the size of it or the z-index, is this possible through CSS only? I made a snippet to explain my question.

So basically i got 3 DIVs in 3 different colors:

```css
#red {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
#blue {
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#yellow {
  width: 80%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to see the color of the red div which acts as a background, but only only the spot where the yellow div is located on the blue div.

So as you can see on the fiddle the spot were the yellow div is located is supposed to be red as the background... is there any possible way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So basically you would want that small part of the div (where your yellow div is) to be transparent? That's not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Also add some graphics i.e how it must look

Comment: @deadfishli yeah exactly

Comment: @GauravRai basicly it should just be a hole without color so im able to see my red div and not the blue one

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because if you make the yellow box transparent, you would see blue from the direct parent, not red from the top parent.

Comment: @UnknownPotato simply color the yellow one in red :D

Comment: Why not make the blue div transparent and have two divs inside it which are blue?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan oh my bad in the real case all colors are transparent and then coloring the yellow one to red wont work, mb >.<

Comment: Will there be content inside those divs that will need to be aligned to the borders of the"yellow" div or it will be only colors?

Comment: @UnknownPotato so your question should actually be: how to make the blue fixed element actually a **Rectilinear polygon** ... or am I mistaken? Also, can you show an image of the result? Sometimes going from A to B takes a simpler path than the initially thought one...

Comment: @emiliopedrollo the yellow div contains content which should be aligned to the borders but the red does not its only a "banner" on top of the page with a transparent background color.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan il add a screenshot :) i added borders so its easier to see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

- Make the *"aside"* DIV `overflow:hidden` and **without background** (yep)
- Add a huge **box-shadow** *blur radius* to the *HOLE* element

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;}html,body{height:100%;}

body{
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/kQEUAmB.jpg) 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

#aside{ /* your ex-blue */
  position:fixed;
  overflow:hidden; /* to contain the child's blue box shadow */
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color:#fff;
}

#hole{ /* your ex-yellow... hole... something */
  width: 80%;
  height: 75px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 300vh blue;  /* huge blue box shadow */
}
```

```html
<div id="aside">
  
  <div id="hole">I HAVE BLUE BOX-SHADOW</div>
  
  <p>OTHER CONTENT ON BLUE</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You are a genius man! Thanks alot it worked exactly like i wanted! =)

Comment: It's sure simpler than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the blue div transparent and then add two divs inside it that will have a blue background so it appears to be a dent on the original blue background (and doesn't use the GPU to calculate shadows thus saving battery on mobile devices while in heavy use):

```css
#out {
  position: relative;
}
#red {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}
#blue {
  width: 29%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0;
}
#blue1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
#blue2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc( 100% - 75px );
  background: blue;
}
#yellow {
  width: 80%;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <div id="red">
  </div>
  <div id="blue">
    <div id="yellow">this is content</div>
    <div id="blue1"></div>
    <div id="blue2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```